# Query returns no row when no data

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running the below query which returns blank row when there is no data. When there is data, the query will return the correct count. Is there a way to return 0 instead of a blank row?

Database is Oracle

```
select alert_count 
from ALERT_LOG 
where alert_name = 'BUCKET' 
and create_date>= trunc(sysdate)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coalesce` to return 0 instead null.

```
select coalesce(sum(alert_count),0)
from alert_log
where alert_name = 'BUCKET' 
and create_date>= trunc(sysdate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregates always return a row (unless there is a `having` clause that excludes all results), so use this:

```
select nvl(sum(alert_count),0)
from   alert_log
where  alert_name = 'BUCKET' and create_date>= trunc(sysdate);
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no aggregation and you just selecting `alert_count` then neither `nvl()` nor `coalesce()` will work since there is no row at all. You can use `union all` to get 0 as default result in this scenario. Try this:

```
select alert_count from ALERT_LOG where alert_name = 'BUCKET' and create_date>= trunc(sysdate)
union all
select 0 from dual where not exists (select alert_count from ALERT_LOG where alert_name = 'BUCKET' and create_date>= trunc(sysdate))
```

If you are using aggregation then you can use `nvl(count(alert_count),0 )` or `coalesce(count(alert_count),0 )`.